# Add small line in \section title

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm trying to duplicate an old document that has a small centered line above each `\section`.  I have not been able to duplicate this when I set the formatting for the `\section`.  (I'm using the titlesec package, among others.)  This is an example of what I've tried:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\rule{.5in}{.02in} \\ \thesection}{0em}{}
```

Is there a way to do this without putting the `{\rule{.5in}{.02in}` before each `\section`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
\titleformat\section{\normalfont\Large\centerline{\hss\rule{.5in}{.02in}\hss}}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: That's pretty close, but the hrule is left justified, rather than centered.  (I'll edit the question to make it clearer, my bad.)  It's ignoring the `\filcenter`, and even trying `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\filcenter{\begin{center}\hrule width.5in\end{center}}}{\thesection}{0em}{}` didn't shift it right.

Comment: @A. R.: Okay, I changed it.

Comment: Genius!  That did the trick.  I modified it slightly as `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\centerline{\hss\rule{.5in}{.02in}\hss}\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}` to center the rest of the text, and put `\section` in the command brackets.  I've been pounding away through the titlesec docs trying to figure it out with the package, but that documentation is quite arcane.

Comment: How do you make the line to go as far as needed according to the text automatically?  Is it possible?