# Flexible rule length in titlesec

Tags: sectioning, rules, titlesec

I'm trying to get a rule just after the `label` of a chapter. (i.e., between "chapter 1" and "This is the chapter 1 title").

So far, I've managed to do this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\normalfont\filcenter}%
{\scshape\Huge \chaptertitlename{} \thechapter{} \\[2.75pt] {\titlerule[1pt]} \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}}%
{15pt}%
{\LARGE\bfseries}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathptmx} % For the drop cap
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %Just to show the frame
\usepackage{lettrine} %For the drop cap

%% Choose one option: titlesec or sectsty
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\normalfont\filcenter}%
    {\scshape\Huge \chaptertitlename{} \thechapter{} \\[2.75pt] {\titlerule[1pt]} \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}}%
    {15pt}%
    {\LARGE\bfseries}

    %\usepackage{sectsty}
    %\chapternumberfont{\centering\sc\Huge\underline}
    %\chaptertitlefont{\centering\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:Intro}


\lettrine[lines=3]{S}{ustained} bipedal locomotion is one of the main characteristics that separates the human being from other primates.  For millennia this has marked a difference not only in the way \textit{Homo Sapiens} moves, but also has played a fundamental part in the evolution and subsequent development of human beings.
\end{document}
```

[image]

but what I want it to look like is this:

[image]

I found a question somewhat related: [Add small line in \section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/add-small-line-in-section-title/8283#8283), but it has a minor inconvenient: it has a fixed length.  I want the rule to be set accordingly to the label width.

I'm also aware that I could achieve Fig.1 results by using the `sectsty` package (that's how I got the picture in the first place), but I want to be able to edit the chapter title of my bibliography so I can set in the same format as the rest of the chapter labels in the document... and I think that is only possible with `titlesec` (`sectsty` does not deal with local definitions, only global... I think)

There is also a possibility to use both packages (`sectsty` to set the global options and then just use `titesec` for the last bibliography part, but I'm not so sure about this one).

Comment: Can't you use `\underline{\chaptertitlename{} \thechapter{}}`? (untested as you didn't show a complete example)-

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I though of that, but the underline seems to be too close to the text.  Is there any way to relocate it?

Comment: Sure, you can use some \strut to move it down. Or check the ulem package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathptmx} % For the drop cap
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %Just to show the frame
\usepackage{lettrine} %For the drop cap
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% Choose one option: titlesec or sectsty
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\normalfont\filcenter}%
    {\begin{tabular}{c}\scshape\Huge \chaptertitlename{} \thechapter{} \\[1ex]\bottomrule[2pt]\end{tabular}}%
    {15pt}%
    {\LARGE\bfseries}

    %\usepackage{sectsty}
    %\chapternumberfont{\centering\sc\Huge\underline}
    %\chaptertitlefont{\centering\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Longer Introduction}
\label{chap:Intro}


\lettrine[lines=3]{S}{ustained} bipedal locomotion is one of the main characteristics that separates the human being from other primates.  For millennia this has marked a difference not only in the way \textit{Homo Sapiens} moves, but also has played a fundamental part in the evolution and subsequent development of human beings.
\end{document}
```

To change the distance of the line, change `[1ex]` to whatever you want. you can change the width of the line, I made it `[2pt]`, which is probably too much. Notice that I `\usepackage{booktabs}`.

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing approach! I didn't think of that!

Comment: I originally thought of `\underline{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1pt}...}`, but it's difficult to change the rule width of `\underline` and the default one is just too thin...